# understand int-vs-trunc relation in double-to-int conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, double, codeblocks

When I run following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    enum { FACTOR = 3 };
    double d = 1.0 / FACTOR;
    double d_i = int(d * FACTOR);
    int i_t = std::trunc(d * FACTOR);
    double d_r = std::round(d * FACTOR);
    cout << d_i << " vs " << i_t << " vs " << d_r << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

from within the Code::Blocks 17.12 IDE (using the all-inclusive tools as I think/hope), I get these confusing results:

```
0 vs 1 vs 1
```

I tried to change the compiler, nothing changed. Finally I installed MinGW-64 version 8.1.0.

My build log shows

```
-------------- Clean: Debug in truncint (compiler: MinGW-w64-32bit)---------------

Cleaned "truncint - Debug"

-------------- Build: Debug in truncint (compiler: MinGW-w64-32bit)---------------

g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -std=c++11 -g -std=c++11  -c C:\Users\[...]\truncint\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\truncint.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
Output file is bin\Debug\truncint.exe with size 65.53 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

But the strange results remain. What could be the cause of this?

Sadly this seems not to be reconstructible with online compilers.

- https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fb36ba43dcbc36f
- https://ideone.com/fWo0a3
- https://ideone.com/f0LpTU
- https://rextester.com/ORSOH1552
- https://rextester.com/MCCS96488

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the strange results are limited to *Debug* builds.

If I switch to *Release*, the output is the same as in VS 2019 and all the online compilers I tested:

```
1 vs 1 vs 1
```

I'm not sure if this can be taken as an answer, but changing the build target solved my actual problem.